# csv recognized as sylk

Tags: excel, csv, openoffice-calc

I've got a downloaded tab-delimiter csv through a PHP script.

If I open it with Excel, it is recognized as a sylk file, and I can't open it (excel can't read it, so in the end I've got a blank sheet); but if I use openoffice I can read it correctly.

I've searched some "strange" char (ex. I've searched a different HEX tab decoding) but nothing seems strange.

Is it possible to "convert" and have it openable through Excel?

Thanks

Comment: Can you open the csv file using a text editor like Notepad, and then do a SaveAs to save it as a csv file?  After doing that, does it open in Excel?

Comment: Nothing changes if I do this trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the first record in the `.csv` file is not :

**ID**

or start with this string; if it is, change it before trying to open it with Excel

Comment: Thanks Gary, first record start with ID; so I've changed it with REF_ID and it works